# Add constants in point cut in aspectj spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I am trying to implement custom logger with aspectj after execution of each function

```
 @AfterReturning(pointcut=" execution (com.manu.utils.Test.succeed(..))")
public void testfn(String a,String b)
{
}
```

I have my util class as follows

```
    class Test{
    public void succeed(Joint point j,String action){
    }
}
```

I would like to know if I can pass a constant to the util class , something like

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut=" execution (com.manu.utils.Test.succeed(..,\"save\"))")
    public void testfn(String a,String b)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Couple of clarifications required (1) The method to be adviced `Test.succeed()` has an arugment of type `Joinpoint` , what is the use of this method ? (2)  Is the requirement to intercept the call to method `Test.succeed()`  and pass `"save"` as the second argument to the method ?

Comment: Or is the requirement to call `Test.succeed()` to log after  the execution of function `testfn(String a,String b)` and a `String` to be passed which informs the logger that it is a `save` ?

Comment: Please note that your pointcut syntax is wrong because the method signature does not contain a return type such as `String` or `*` (any). Correct syntax would e.g. be `execution(* com.manu.utils.Test.succeed(..))`. Furthermore, please edit the question in order to clearly explain what you want to do. What do you mean by "pass a constant to the util class"? Show in your method bodies what you want to do, don't just leave them empty because your words are totally unclear. Please learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is, thank you.

Comment: Besides, passing a value to a method **after** the method has finished execution already (you use `@AfterReturning`) is impossible unless you have a time machine.